# Restoring Placeholder to Original Value

Tags: jquery, html

I have a comment box and having trouble restoring the placeholder after a user types into it and presses enter.

Here is my textarea:

```
<textarea title="Write a comment..." itemID="@item.ID" class="comment" placeholder="Write a comment..." autocomplete="off" role="textbox" id="comment" style="margin-top:8px"></textarea>
```

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't work:

```
    $(msgBox).val($(msgBox).attr('defaultValue'));
```

and

```
    $(msgBox).val('');
```

Not only does the placeholder not get reset, but the carriage return is still here.  The textarea becomes blank with the cursor on the second line.

Comment: Does the textarea have an attribute named defaultValue? Try `attr('placeholder')` instead.

Comment: What browser are you using? Placeholder is supported automatically by all modern (HTML5) browsers.

Comment: I'm using Chrome.  The placeholder works, but I need to reset it after the user presses Return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use a `#` sign for selecting an element by `id`, also you should add a attribute name, note that in your example there is no `defaultValue` attribute, and the selector returns nothing, I have added a `blur` event which fires after the textarea loses it's focus, and if the value of teaxarea is empty it sets the `placeholder` attribute value as it's value:

```
$('#comment').blur(function(){
   if ($.trim(this.value) == "") {
      $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
   }
})
```

Comment: Selecting the element by id or by class, it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @fudgey what makes a difference?

Comment: Well, as it is now, your answer is wrong. The html from the question has `comment` as a class name. And what I mean is, even if the question had `comment` as an id, your answer is still the same as what the OP says didn't work: `$(msgBox).val($(msgBox).attr('defaultValue'));`

Comment: @fudgey yes, but it has an id named `comment` as well `id="comment"`

Comment: ok my mistake, it does have an id... but he still stated that that method didn't work. And maybe you are right in that `msgBox` may not be defined properly.

Comment: I still am having trouble clearing the field.  When I assign '' to it, I still get the cursor on the second line.  When I press backspace the placeholder appears, so I went ahead and accepted the answer, although I'm having that carriage return issue.

Comment: Solved carriage return issue... had a kepress event which should have been a keyup event.